# Extract values ​from specific parts of a text file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a [text file](https://pastebin.com/KURu0Tn3) from which I need to extract some values, but several times I get more than one value between the beginning and the last line that starts with `0089` (CONVENIO) in the quadrant.

With my code I can only make it write in the txt the title I defined and it keeps repeating the first agreement found, but I need it to scroll through the text and bring me new information from the other quadrants.

I need the loop as it can have multiple covenants, for this reason I can't directly "anchor" the lines in a size forecast.

```
import re
import os

inicio = ('  YM-INFRA-CASH MANAGMENT                                               DEST.: 001-0001-CENTRAL                                      ')

lista = []
contador = 3
banco = ' 0089'

convenio = ''

with open(caminho + '/Downloads/TESTE.txt', 'r') as arquivo:
    for line in arquivo:
        if line.strip() == inicio.strip():

            localizar = arquivo.readlines()

            inicio = localizar[contador]
            van = inicio[13:17]
            nomevan = inicio[20:50].strip()

            inicio = localizar[contador + 1]
            ag = inicio[13:17]
            nomeag = inicio[20:50].strip()

            inicio = localizar[contador + 2]
            cliente = inicio[13:50].strip()

            contadorum = 9

            while localizar[contadorum][1:5] == '0033':
                convenio = localizar[contadorum][1:22].strip()
                narqrem = localizar[contadorum][22:34].strip()
                bytesrem = localizar[contadorum][34:51].strip()
                narqret = localizar[contadorum][51:63].strip()
                bytesret = localizar[contadorum][63:81].strip()
                totalbytes = localizar[contadorum][81:99].strip()
                percrateio = localizar[contadorum][99:112].strip()

                print(van, nomevan)
                print(ag, nomeag)
                print(cliente)

                print(convenio, narqrem, bytesrem, narqret, bytesret, totalbytes, percrateio)
                lista.append(convenio + narqrem + bytesrem + narqret + bytesret + totalbytes + percrateio +'\n')

                with open(caminho + '/Downloads/testefim.txt', 'w') as consolidado:
                    consolidado.write('CONVENIO' + ';' + 'N ARQ REMES'  + ';' + 'BYTES REMES' + ';' + 'N ARQ.RET.' + ';' + 'BYTES RET.' + ';' + 'TOTAL BYTES' + ';' + '% RATEIO' + '\n')
                    for linha in lista:
                        consolidado.write(convenio + ';' + narqrem + ';' + bytesrem + ';' + narqret + ';' + bytesret + ';' + totalbytes + ';' + percrateio + '\n')

                    consolidado.close()
            else:
                pass

    arquivo.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for sharing your code and some sample input. Right now, your code does not produce anything. What do you want the output to be for the `TESTE VANS.txt` input?

Comment: I need print my variables (convenio + ';' + narqrem + ';' + bytesrem + ';' + narqret + ';' + bytesret + ';' + totalbytes.......)
And write this variables in testefim.txt